# Convert Oracle SQL to Microsoft SQL Server - eliminate CONNECT BY PRIOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, maximo

Can someone please show me how to replace `CONNECT BY PRIOR` in the following script? This may look familiar to some of you as I am trying to build a hierarchy from Maximo data.

```
SELECT
    lh.location,
    loc.description locdescription,
    assetnum,
    asset.description,
    LEVEL*8-1 ||'pt' pad
FROM
    lochierarchy_vw AS lh
JOIN
    locations_vw AS loc ON loc.location = lh.location
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    asset_vw AS asset ON asset.location = lh.location 
CONNECT BY PRIOR 
    lh.location=lh.parent 
START WITH
    lh.parent IS NULL
```

I've tried a form of recursive Select but could not get it correct.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: This looks like standard recursive cte 101, which parts did you have trouble translating? I'd suggest just iterate the hierarchy table inside the cte and join the other table outside, because recursive ctes don't like LEFT JOINs

Comment: CONNECT BY PRIOR / START WITH is specific to Oracle Database and does not exists in any other RDBMS. The ISO SQL standard use recursive queries with Common Table Expression (CTE), eg queries begging by WITH and doing the recursion with an UNION ALL between the CTE and the target table.